# how to create object of class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my core php code:

```
require('common/Client.php');              // include php wrapper  class
require('common/GrantType/IGrantType.php');// include php wrapper  class//
require('common/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php'); // include php wrapper  class//
const CLIENT_ID     = '***********'; //generated from base_camp api//
const CLIENT_SECRET ='***********'; 
const REDIRECT_URI           = '***********';
const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token';

     session_start();

$client = new OAuth2\my_class(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
if (!isset($_GET['code']))
 {
   $_SESSION['org'] = $_GET['org'];
  $auth_url = $client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
  header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
  die('Redirect');
    }
   else
  {
    $params = array( 'type' => 'web_server', 'client_id' => CLIENT_ID, 'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI, 'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET, 'code' => $_GET['code']);
 $response = $client->getAccessToken(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params);

$client->setAccessToken($response['result']['access_token']);

 $org = $_SESSION['org'].'_ess';
 mysql_connect('localhost','root','*******') or die('Cannot connect to database !');
 mysql_select_db($org) or die('No database found in mysql !');

$gcntct = mysql_query("select * from e_users");
}
```

How do I initialize object of another class in  mvc, I have adopt new method  by initialize new by namespace name and class its show non existing class error.

```
    oath2 is namespace and client is library class name.
    function a()
    {

   $this->library('client');
```

How do pass `clientid` and  secret key in during object creation codeigniter as if you    would see my core php code I have initialize object with new operator and pass values , so how could we initialize object of class client and namespace with passing values in constructor.

```
       } 
     client.php lib
     namesapce oath2
     class client
     {

  public function __construct($client_id, $client_secret, $client_auth =          self::AUTH_TYPE_URI, $certificate_file = null)
         {
     if (!extension_loaded('curl')) {
         throw new Exception('The PHP extention curl must be installed to use this library.', Exception::CURL_NOT_FOUND);
      }

     $this->client_id     = $client_id;
     $this->client_secret = $client_secret;
     $this->client_auth   = $client_auth;
     $this->certificate_file = $certificate_file;
     if (!empty($this->certificate_file)  && !is_file($this->certificate_file)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('The certificate file was not found', InvalidArgumentException::CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND);
      }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a library in Codeigniter and load it.
[See here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and [here](http://blog.3dmick.com/2012/08/creating-own-libraries-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: here is my updated code $this->load->library('Client');
     $a=$this->client->getAuthenticationUrl(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, REDIRECT_URI);
     echo $a;

Comment: you means to say that we can  function directly by library name in mvc , and how should we intailize object of class

Comment: You have defined your class as `client` and loading `Client`. Try `$this->load->library('client'); $this->client->getAuthenticationUrl();`

Comment: still problem , code:$client = new OAuth2\Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET); here i have used in oath as a namespace as i googled codigntor donot support support namespaces how should i declare object of the class.

Comment: Describe your library file structure and where is `Client`?

Comment: see my code last section  client is oath wrapper library and how should i avoid namespace as if codintaor not support it.

Comment: So why are you using namespaces? Just create libraries.
include Oauth class in your library file. See here. An example wrapper library for facebook https://github.com/bugzbrown/codeigniter-facebook-lib/blob/master/facebook.php